# Where can I find plugins for meteor js?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, plugins

Where can I find the plugin libary for meteor js?
And can anyone recommend plugins for meteor js, which for example analyze and visualize large data?

Comment: You can install any Npm package. Besides that there is atmospherejs.com for Meteor packages

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Meteor!
You have two ways to get packages/plugins for Meteor. For packages that are closely integrated with Meteor you will use Meteor's own packaging system. You can search for packages on https://atmospherejs.com/ or https://packosphere.com/
You can easily install these packages by running `meteor add namespace:name-of-package`.

Packages that are not directly connected to Meteor you can get like in any other Node.js project via npm. The difference is that for Meteor you add `meteor` before the npm call, so something like this: `meteor npm i --save react`. This is to ensure that you get the correct package bundle for the Node environment that your version of Meteor is using.

If you want more detailed breakdown check out the Meteor Guide: https://guide.meteor.com/atmosphere-vs-npm.html